# Adding a definite number of rows in a table in java

Tags: android

I have to create a table in java and the number of rows are not known prior to execution. So i have the following java code which creates the table. However , when I try to add the table row to the table layout it throws an illegal state exception. How would I solve this issue?

```
 Map<Integer,TableRow> kMap = null;
   for(int i=0;i<noofrows;i++)
   {

         TableRow test=new TableRow(this);
          kMap = new HashMap<Integer,TableRow>();
         for(int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
         {
           kMap.put(k, test);
         }

     }
TextView empty = new TextView(this);

// title column/row
TextView title = new TextView(this);
title.setText("Java Weather Table");


TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams();
params.span = 6;

rowTitle.addView(title, params);

//Add some more fields to the rows

table1.addView(rowTitle);
table1.addView(kMap.get(0));
//Exception is thrown
table1.addView(kMap.get(1));
table1.addView(kMap.get(2));
//table1.addView(rowConditions);

setContentView(table1);
```

Log cat trace:

```
09-14 07:02:50.265: E/AndroidRuntime(384): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
09-14 07:02:50.265: E/AndroidRuntime(384):  at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:1970)
09-14 07:02:50.265: E/AndroidRuntime(384):  at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1865)
09-14 07:02:50.265: E/AndroidRuntime(384):  at android.widget.TableLayout.addView(TableLayout.java:418)
09-14 07:02:50.265: E/AndroidRuntime(384):  at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1822)
09-14 07:02:50.265: E/AndroidRuntime(384):  at android.widget.TableLayout.addView(TableLayout.java:400)
09-14 07:02:50.265: E/AndroidRuntime(384):  at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1802)
09-14 07:02:50.265: E/AndroidRuntime(384):  at android.widget.TableLayout.addView(TableLayout.java:391)
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the only problem with your code, but the issue you're complaining about is caused because you only created one TableRow and are adding it three times.  Your kMap needs to contain 3 different TableRow objects, not the same object 3 times.

Comment: Any idea how to dynamically create n number of tablerows in a for loop and put them into a kmap as I dont know the number of rows before hand?